# AngularJS $http call to twitter fails but works when using XMLHttpRequest (IE9)

Tags: angularjs, http, xmlhttprequest

I'm using AngularJS 1.3.0 and trying to call the twitter api, my first code snippit works but once i'm trying to do it in angular $http request it fails!

IE9 throws an Access Denied

```
var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials';

function callOtherDomain() {
    if(invocation) {    
      invocation.open('POST', url, true);
      invocation.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
      invocation.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic [MYBASE64ENCODING]');

      invocation.onreadystatechange = function(e, data){
          console.dir(data);
      };
      invocation.send(); 
    }
}
callOtherDomain();
```

Angular (version 1.3.0)

```
    angular.module("Twitter",[])
           .controller("DefaultController",["$http","$scope",function($http, $scope){

               $scope.results = "None";
               $scope.getAccessToken = function() {
                   $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";            
                   $http.defaults.headers.post.Authorization = "Basic [MYBASE64ENCODING]";
                   console.dir($http.defaults.headers.post);

                   $http({                    
                      method: "post",                    
                      url: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token",   
                      data:"grant_type=client_credentials"                
                   })
                   .success(function(html) {                         
                      $scope.results = html;                     
                   })
                  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                      $scope.results = "failed";
                   });
           }    
    }])
```

Comment: Have you tried using something like Fiddler to compare the requests being made?

Comment: Nope not yet, will do as soon installed fiddler

Comment: I'm having the same issue, it looks like Angular isn't adding the Authorization header according to Chrome's network log. Did you get anywhere?

Comment: I've just tried making the same HTTP request but to a local URL. Angular adds the Authorization header happily. Angular 1.3 isn't adding the authorization header for cross origin requests.